# I have struggled to get my rewrite rules to work the way I want them too

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mybb

This is going to be a lengthy post.  Please bear with me.

> ## My Directory Structure

```
public_html
    agentc0re
       blog
       forum
       etc..
    other doamins
```

> ## My .htaccess files

### public_html

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -MultiViews -Indexes
<files .htaccess>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</files>

ErrorDocument 404 /agentc0re/404/index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.agentc0re.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://agentc0re.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.agentc0re.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://agentc0re.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?agentc0re.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agentc0re/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /agentc0re/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?agentc0re.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ agentc0re/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### agentc0re

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -MultiViews -Indexes
<files .htaccess>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /agentc0re

RewriteRule ^Home/?$ /index.php?page= [L]
RewriteRule ^Blog/?$ /index.php?page=blog [L]
RewriteRule ^Forum/?$ /index.php?page=forum/index [L]
RewriteRule ^Sub_Counter/?$ /index.php?page=SubCounter/subCounter [L]
RewriteRule ^AboutMe/?$ /index.php?page=aboutme [L]
RewriteRule ^Contact/?$ /index.php?page=contact [L]

RewriteBase /agentc0re/forum

RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

### blog

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -MultiViews -Indexes
<files .htaccess>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?page=blog [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

### forum

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -MultiViews -Indexes
<files .htaccess>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</files>
#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /agentc0re/forum

    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
            SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

> ## What Does This Do

#### public_html

redirects www version regardless of http(s) to the non www version of my website.  Then it removes agentc0re from the URL.

#### agentc0re

I use dynamic php inclusion for my site.  aka loading my header, content, footer all via php includes.  Thats what the first set of rewrite rules do.  They make the Menu bar on my site work...kinda (more info on that).  The next set that has a rewrite base of "/agentc0re/forum" is there because if you were to view my site from http://example.com/Forum (rewrite rule to my index.php include file) then the forum links don't work properly.

#### blog

This effectively loads the blog alongside my header+menu like the main page.  without this, wordpress would just load by itself.

#### forum

Default rewrite rules for myBB

> ## What needs to be fixed

**Blog issues**

If you haven't figured it out by now [my webiste is this](http://agentc0re.com).  If you look at the menu links they look user friendly/nice.  They also all go where they should.  You can see this by hovering over them and looking at the bottom of your browser to see where they point to.

Now click on **Blog**.  Well this is where shit gets weird.  Now all the menu links have changed.  They're Blog/Home, Blog/Blog...etc.  **This is one item i need fixed**

Secondly, click on a link in my blog.  NOW the damn menu links change even more.  I assume this is related to the above problem.  I have no clue why, but i know it's not wordpress related as it happens to my forum links as well.  UNLESS they both do weird shit that causes this.

**Forum issues**

Similarly to the Blog, when you click on links within the forum, the links for the menu change.  But initially clicking on Forum doesn't induce similar results like when you click on Blog.

> ## What I'd Like to see happen

**For blog**

When someone clicks on the Blog in the Menu and they navigate within the blog, links are show to be

```
 http://example.com/Blog/*
```

**For Forum**

Like the blog, I'd like the same thing to happen for the Forum.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file, the section:

```html
<div id='cssmenu' class='align-center'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='Home'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='Blog'>Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='Forum'>Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Youtube Resources</a>
      <ul>
        <!--<li><a href='index.php?page=/SubCounter/subCounter' target="_top">YTG Sub Counter</a></li>-->
        <li><a href='Sub_Counter' target="_top">YTG Sub Counter</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Other Sites</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='http://extralifealerts.com' target='_blank'>Extra-Life Alerts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='http://learnix.net' target='_blank'>Learnix.net</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!--<li><a href='index.php?page=aboutme'>About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href='index.php?page=contact'>Contact</a></li>-->
    <li><a href='AboutMe'>About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='Contact'>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

needs to have absolute links, instead of relative ones. So, for eg. change the `a[href]`s to:

```
    <li><a href='/Home'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/Blog'>Blog</a>
    </li>
```

and that's all.

Comment: Home, Blog, Folder, Sub_Counter, AboutMe & Contact are not folders.  They're just pretty names for actual locations.  Would you like me to edit my post and add in my index.php as well so you can see how it works with my agentc0re folders .htaccess?

Comment: @Jonathan The `href` value is reference to a new page relative to your own webpage. Edit the links as I told above, and you'll see them working.

Comment: Well sir, despite mythoughts of that not working because they were not existing folders, i tried it anyways.  Now my menu behaves like i want it to, ESP in the blog section.  Most importantly, it works.  So that's one issue down.  Are you have to help with the others by chance?  Also, Thank you! :D

Comment: @Jonathan You can solve all the problems by adding appropriate `<base>` tags in each of the files' `head` sections. The problem is too specific, and more time consuming than I can spare to help you out with each of pages. Read about relative and absolute links on HTML/PHP pages.